# Measure the consumed mb on the internet

Tags: c#

I want to get the number of consumed MBs on the internet by code..

I know that it can be done manually:
Settings -> Network & Internet -> Data Usage (Windows 10)

photo:
[image: Settings -> Network & Internet -> Data Usage (Windows 10)]

But how can I find this by code?

I want the number for the **whole system**, NOT ONLY MY APPLICATION.

For example, I want my code to show: *The GB used this month was 3.21!*

Comment: did you want only total usage or set/receive data is required?

Comment: @dotctor I haven't tried anything so far.. Just because I don't know from what to start..

Comment: @Kunal_Kakkad Yes, I want only the total usage

Comment: To be clear, do you want the number for your whole system for the last 30 days (in the case of that picture, 3.21GB) or for your specific application or for another duration of time?

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren For whole the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following snippet which will give you total sent and received data. You just need to sum it out:

```
private static void GetTrafficStatistics()
{
    PerformanceCounterCategory performanceCounterCategory = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");
    string instance = performanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames()[0]; // 1st NIC !
    PerformanceCounter performanceCounterSent = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", instance);
    PerformanceCounter performanceCounterReceived = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", instance);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bytes sent: {0}k\tbytes received: {1}k", performanceCounterSent.NextValue() / 1024, performanceCounterReceived.NextValue() / 1024);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

PS:It is using `System.Diagnostics.dll`

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: @Kunal_Kakkad After using the code,I realized that it doesn't return 3.21 GB.. So,..it didn't help me.. :/